# UptimeRobot working but replit dies in short period of time

Tags: discord, discord.js, cloud, nodes, hosting

After like 10 minutes or so, bot goes offline but the UptimeRobot is always running, i think replit is shutting down behind the scene. although, i have tried to implement this piece of code

```
client.on('disconnect', function(erMsg, code) {
  console.log('----- Bot disconnected from Discord with code', code, 'for reason:', erMsg, '-----');
  client.connect();
});
```

but even then it shut down!!

I am trying to have my bot up and running all the time, i need some information or some code to fix have replit restart again automatically. Or maybe, i can use some other free service to get my bot running.

Comment: Repl.it has their own paid service to keep processes running. Naturally, they block redundant requests that will do this for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because they are blocking requests coming from UptimeRobot. Which means they don't want you to uptime your repl. So you shouldn't be using these.

Comment: any other alternative to have my bot be online all the time ?